# System.Linq.GroupBy Key not binding in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7.1

```
list.ItemsSource=db.Templates.GroupBy(t=>t.CategoryName);
```

in xaml:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

After this code. Don't show any text in TextBlock. I'm changing Text binding like this

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

TextBlock Text shown like this `System.Linq.Lookup^2+Grouping[System.String,Model.Template]`

I'm debugging and checking `Key` property. this is not null.

Why `Key` don't bind in TextBlock?

How to show group title in Textblock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm - unfortunate.  The reason is because the result of the `GroupBy()` call is an instance of `System.Linq.Lookup<,>.Grouping`.  `Grouping` is a nested class of the `Lookup<,>` class, however `Grouping` is marked as `internal`.

Security restrictions in Silverlight don't let you bind to properties defined on non-public types, even if those properties are declared in a public interface which the class implements.  The fact that the object instance you are binding to is of a non-public concrete type means that you can only bind to public properties defined on any public *base classes* of that type.

You could build a public shim class to act as a view model for the grouping:

```
public class MyGrouping {
  public string Key {get; internal set;}
}

list.ItemsSource=db.Templates.GroupBy(t=>t.CategoryName)
                             .Select(g => new MyGrouping { Key = g.Key });
```

Comment: Also, note that you may have seen some error message about the property not being available in the Output window of Visual Studio if you had the debugger attached.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I had similar problem recently, so I decided to post another solution.

You can create a converter and return the value of Key from it

```
public class GroupNameToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var grouping = (IGrouping<string, [YOUR CLASS NAME]>) value;

            return grouping.Key;
        }

    }
```

and in Xaml you don't bind to Key, but to the grouping itself.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource groupNameToStringConverter}}" />
```