# DataBinding to ILookup

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have an `ILookup<string, MyObject>` representing a grouping of MyObjects in my Windows Phone 8 app. I'm having problems getting the items in the grouping to appear in a LongListSelector

My xaml is as follows. Firstly I have a Pivot control

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="pivotItem" 
             Title="" 
             Padding="0" 
             HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource pivotItemHeader}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Pages, ElementName=fixturesPageBase}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource fixtureItemTemplate}"/>
```

I have a header template which is like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="pivotItemHeader">
        <TextBlock Foreground="#FF22AA15" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This works fine and displays the correct header for each pivot item. Then I have the item template which is as follows

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="fixtureItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Controls:LongListSelector x:Name="fixtureList" 
                               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FixtureItem}" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This is where I am stuck. I'm guessing ItemsSource="{Binding}" is not correct? It doesnt display any of the content in my FixtureItem template. The grid and the long list selector in the above xaml is created and displayed but the lists items are not.

Comment: That {Binding} will get the first datacontext up the tree roughly speaking...

Comment: you should probably check the binding in "FixtureItem" resource.

Comment: How did you define your ILookup? How did you define your MyObject?

Comment: @igrali what do you mean how are they defined? They are defined in c# code

Comment: @terrybozzio What should I be checking for? If I set my FixtureItem template to a very simple
`<DataTemplate x:Key="FixtureItem">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
  </DataTemplate>` 
where Name is a property of MyObject, nothing displays.

Comment: Your definition *should be* correct ... right?  (After all, `IGrouping<T1, T2>` inherits `IEnumerable<T2>`.)  I recall having a similar problem trying to bind to the result of a `GroupBy`.  It turned out that the runtime was using a slightly different type, breaking the binding.  Eventually I created a wrapper class for `IGrouping` to hold each key and its values.  (Side note: have you checked the output window for any binding errors?)

Comment: Maybe related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8342720/1001985

Comment: From the answer at the link, here is the root of the problem: `"the result of the GroupBy() call is an instance of System.Linq.Lookup<,>.Grouping. Grouping is a nested class of the Lookup<,> class, however Grouping is marked as internal."`  Bottom line: create your own class to wrap `IGrouping`.

Comment: Sounds like a plan @McGarnagle. I'll test it out and get back to you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42992/discussion-between-real-world-and-mcgarnagle)