# Binding Listbox in windows phone

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I have 2 textblocks in a listbox datatemplate. 
I want to display list of names in alphabetical order. The first textblock should show the first character of names only at the start of the string with that character and the second textblock should show the string.

Please check the below link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mdtu.png

It is like:

```
A   Ana
    Andrew
    Andy
B   Bane
    Bob
C   Chris
    Christian
    Catherine
```

I tried this: 
XAML:

```
  <ListBox Height="331"   Name="lstBoxPlayers"  MinHeight="200" MinWidth="150" Margin="0,0,0,20" SelectionChanged="lstBoxPlayers_SelectionChanged"
                 Tap="lstBoxPlayers_Tap" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" MinWidth="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0">

                        <Grid Background="White" MinWidth="200" Height="50">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock x:Name="Abrev" Text="{Binding Path=PlayerShortName[0]}" FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" Height="Auto" Width="26" TextAlignment="Center">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding PlayerShortName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" Height="29" MaxWidth="160"  Margin="-25,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

code behind:

```
 lstBoxPlayers.ItemsSource = PlayerList;  //List of string
```

Comment: I have added my xaml code. Please check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupBy to form Alphabetic groups and then bind the resultant Collection of groups to the ListBox..

The code behind would look like:

```
lstBoxPlayers.ItemsSource = PlayerList.GroupBy( p => p.PlayerShortName[ 0 ] );
```

And the Xaml in you Grid would look like:

```
<!--Key of the Group-->
<TextBlock x:Name="Abrev" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" Height="Auto" Width="26" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>

<!--Values of the Group-->
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="-25,0,0,0" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding PlayerShortName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" Height="29" MaxWidth="160" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Is the GroupBy populating the ITemsSource properly?

Comment: No. The list is being populated with listitems but the textblocks are not being bounded.

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342720/system-linq-groupby-key-not-binding-in-silverlight